# Storing phone numbers country code

Tags: database

I split the phone number in 2 parts:

- country prefix(e.g. +49)
- phone number without leading 0

My question is, which is the best approach to store the country code **As it is (+49)** or a **Foreign key** to a countries table?

Answer (score 2):

You shoud use The Normal Forms for Databases.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

there are rules to roll with such a problem.

/M

Answer (score 0):

The choice is dependent upon:

1. No. or records
2. The database used
3. No. of relationships with other tables

As, country code would be a repeating column it could be placed in a varchar type column as it is e.g. +91-9654637268 .This will allow different formats of the phone number but no validation at database level that the entered value must be a number that you will need to validate at code level .Using a varchar must be the first choice for storing the phone numbers with their country codes as it will be faster by avoiding joins.

---

But if you need good amount of manipulation use a bigint which will store the number as e.g. 9764536377443 where first two digits are country code and rest of the digits are the phone number part.

---

Or you could have a separate column for the country code which would add an unnecessary join but could be helpful if the country code is needed at several places and must be well validated and constrained whihc could also be achieved by using any of the above techniques.

Hope it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**Transactional Database**

If this is a transactional database (lots of updating), or a general purpose database (querying and updating) then use Database normalisation as Jonathan says. So have a table called Country with structure

```
| ID | CountyCode | CountryName |
| 1  | +49        | Germany     |
| 2  | +1         | USA         |
```

This way you can keep the country code and the describing information related to it away from the data about the telephone number. So say a country changes its name or country code, rather than having to update each effected row in the telephone number table, you just update the one row in the Country table.

Then a table(s) for the rest of the telephone number (depending on whether you want to split up area code etc..) with a column that references as a foreign key the CountyCode ID

```
| ID | CountyCodeID | TelNumber |
| 1  | 1            | 12345     |
```

However bear in mind that this is a general purpose way of doing things, in query heavy situations with larger amounts of data (dataMart, datawarehouse) then a different approach is best see [Star Schemas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema)